# Atom how to run jasmine test?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, atom-editor

I try use `Atom` editor and `angular2`.
My tests are passed using terminal command

```
ng test
```

I have tried some install and start some plugins like: `mocha-test-runner`, `atom-jasmine`, `jasmine-runner`, `rspec` to run tests using atom editor... no one can run tests.

Recommend me please good atom plugin to run angular2 tests.

Comment: you should configure **autoWatch: true** in your karmaconfig file

Comment: @Aravind It was configured from very beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WallabyJs is a great tool for having your tests running in an automated way, it also works with many IDEs/text editors.

https://wallabyjs.com/

(This is a paid tool)

Comment: Daniel, it is not simply test runner, it's different test framework and I have to care to configure it... I have spend a lot of time for research of my current configuration (generated automatically), I'm not sure it is good idea spend same for `wallabyjs`, but i'll try it in next few days.

Comment: Hey Sergii, are you saying you want to use a different test framework or that using Wallaby means you are using a different framework?
Wallaby is just a runner that you can hook into different frameworks so it will work with your jasmine set-up. I may have misunderstood your comment though.

Comment: I'm new in js testing, and I need a time to configure `wallabyjs`, in default configuration `package.json` I have mapped instruction `ng test`, and this instruction calls all tests... I need good plugin & I need time to configure it, I've found some examples, but my level here needs working `hello world` example :), or detail instruction for beginner, so I'm working on it.

Comment: This is not exactly i need, but it is good to know and use. thanks.

Comment: Ok, no worries.